# How can I set (override) all items in hash

Tags: redis, servicestack

I want to set all entries in Hash. (SetAllEntriesToHash)

It must Clear all items in hash before running.

It is opposite of GetAllEntriesFromHash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple options here.

**1)** You could let ServiceStack take care of this for you by using the high level Redis API.

```
public class Poco
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

...

// Client
var client = new RedisClient("localhost", 6379);

// This will store the object for you in a Redis hash.
client.StoreAsHash(new Poco { Id = 1, Name = "Test Name", Description = "Test Description" });

// This will fetch it back for you.
var result = client.GetFromHash<Poco>(1);
```

This approach will disconnect you from having to deal directly with the hashing particulars.  ServiceStack will figure out everything for you and stuff the object you send it into a hash automatically.  If you want to update that object, just send it a new one with the same ID.

The flip-side of this is that you're giving up control of how your data is stored in Redis for an easier programming experience.

**2)** You handle all of the stuff yourself.  There is no *SetAllEntriesToHash* function pre-built.

```
// Client
var client = new RedisClient("localhost", 6379);

// Clear all existing keys
var keysToClear =  new Dictionary<string,string>();
client.GetHashKeys("xxxxx").ForEach(k => keysToClear.Add(k, ""));
client.SetRangeInHash("xxxxx", keysToClear);

// Save new key/values.  
client.SetRangeInHash("xxxxx", new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("1", "value 1"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("2", "value 2"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("3", "value 3"),
});
```

Alternatively, it may be easier just to delete and recreate the hash.

I would also like to draw your attention to **RedisNativeClient**.  It allows you to run Redis commands that directly map to http://redis.io/commands.

Comment: client.Hashes[hashId].Clear();
client.Hashes[hashId].AddRange(hash);

Comment: Yup, that's a delete and re-add.  Probably the easiest.