# Clear X key from Hashes

Tags: redis, servicestack

There is 3 Hashes in my redis database:

**set:recentbooks**

**set:badbooks**

**set:funnybooks**

All hashes contain book Ids as key.

I want to remove the book that has 234 Id from all hashes.

How can I do this:

- Lua Scripting
- Pipeline
- Other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the ServiceStack redis client API, you could pipeline your delete requests like thus:

```
var client = new RedisClient("localhost", 6379);

using (var pipeline = client.CreatePipeline())
{
    pipeline.QueueCommand(r => r.RemoveEntryFromHash("set:recentbooks", "234"));
    pipeline.QueueCommand(r => r.RemoveEntryFromHash("set:badbooks", "234"));
    pipeline.QueueCommand(r => r.RemoveEntryFromHash("set:funnybooks", "234"));

    // All deletes will be sent at once.
    pipeline.Flush();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jeffi. do you have any idea about other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455010/how-can-i-set-override-all-items-in-hash

Answer (score 1):

Using a LUA script, it's easy:

```
EVAL "redis.call('HDEL',KEYS[2],KEYS[1]);
      redis.call('HDEL',KEYS[3],KEYS[1]);
      redis.call('HDEL',KEYS[4],KEYS[1]);" 
      4 234 set:recentbooks set:badbooks set:funnybooks
```

I've never used ServiceStack, but with the info above you have what's required to invoke the redis client in ServiceStack to delete the keys.

You can also write the lua script in a file, then call it like this with parameters:

```
redis-cli> EVAL "$(cat myscript.lua)" 4 234 set:recentbooks set:badbooks set:funnybooks
```